# gacutil is showing version 3.5 instead of 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, gac

I have Windows 7, with .net 3.5 installed as a Windows feature, and Visual Studio 2012, which installed .Net framework 4.5 on my system (I can see that under Programs and Features) but when I run gacutil from VS Developer command prompt, it shows version 3.5. how can I switch to version 4.5?

Thanks.

Comment: Install a later version of VS or the Windows SDK.

Comment: i checked "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools" folder the gacutil version is 4.0   i have VS 2015 installed. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools" have gacutil version 4.6 . i think gacutil version is independent of .net version

Comment: Hum ... interesting. Thanks @jophyjob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i checked

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1
>   Tools"

folder the gacutil version is 4.0 i have VS 2015 installed.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6
>   Tools"

have gacutil version 4.6 . i think gacutil version is independent of .net version